# Php can't read cookie for 2 minutes

Tags: php, cookies, yii2

my problem is, php can't read the cookie on server for 2 minutes.  After 2 minutes it works. I write a token to cookie with ajax request.

```
success: function (data) {document.cookie = "token="+data.data.token+";path=/"; window.location.href="/";}
```

then in controller for index action i wrote

```
echo $_COOKIE["token"];
    die();
```

it doesn't echo anything for 2 minutes. After that it echo the cookie.
But when i change the cookie, it shows the old cookie which doesn't exist anymore.
The code works normally on local and my test server. But doesn't work the real server/
i use Yii2 for my project.

Comment: First of all, please go read [ask]. We need a bit more & proper info. So far, this simply sounds like some sort of caching issue, but we have no details about your system whatsoever yet.

Comment: This is the first time that i ask question here. Thanks for your advice. i have updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the server. Cache was activated, That's why system couldn't write sessions or cookies.